Laravel queue execute one instance of job at a time
This is more of a theoretical question.
I have an application used simultaneously by hundreds of users. This application largely consists of consuming an API endpoint.
This API only allows one request at a time, so I thought I should queue the requests and send them one by one.
When reading the Laravel documentation I saw the middleware "WithoutOverlapping", but I think it consists of avoiding the overlap of a job on a particular object, while in my case there is no object but a request to an API with dynamic information.
What I would need is to be able to queue multiple instances of the same job and have the worker only run one at a time.
Maybe this is de default behaviour of queues, but i cant find anything that confirms that.
